# Role Of Whirling Blades in Fantasy Society (RPG Classes)

Tags: society, magic

Recap-How Classes Work: In my book, a mysterious pulse of energy sent a young man named John into another world called Alendyias. This event resulted in John becoming Rorjon, a bluish ghost-like being (Kanyeri) that acts as a force of good, guiding, advising, and blessing the people of his new world (Alendyias). One of these blessings was based on John's love of RPGs like DnD, namely Classes. All Classes magically enhance one's potential (capacity), but only within the limits of their held Class. The level of this enhancement increases as the Class-holder grows and gains experience in their Class, and this increase is measured by Levels.

This question is about the Whirling Blade Class, a hybrid of the Dancer and Warrior Classes which falls into the Speed, Support Combat categories. Like all Classes, this Class is almost invariably inherited or granted at birth, magically enhancing the holder's potential. However, this Class's enhancements concern physical attractiveness, strength, endurance, speed, grace, charisma, and skill in battle.

Like a Dancer, a Whirling Blade is capable of performances so moving they can affect something like strength or speed, with very movement of their dance causing a ripple in the arcane. However, unlike a Dancer, a Whirling Blade can fight *and* dance at the same time, they are much stronger and have actual combat skills (most Dancers don't), and their dance's effects are suited for the battlefield.

Here are some examples:

1. Hastening Dance-The Dancer's hastened movements inspire urgency in their allies and speed their movements drastically as long as they are within three miles. Oddly enough, they consume as much energy as they were before for as long as the Dance is ongoing.
2. Inspiring Dance-This dance empassions allies within three miles. They gain increased motivation and determination and may or may not gain inspiration.
3. Emboldening Dance-This dance awakens their ally's inner courage and strength (as long as they are within three-mile range), which is perfect for a full-force attack or a rout.
4. Revitalizing Dance-This dance only affects those within a nine-foot radius and is quite draining, taking 1/4 of a Whirling Blade's maximum energy. It seals the wounds of allies (only to a certain extent) and reinvigorates them, but it can't restore lost limbs or heal fatal wounds.
5. Bewitching Dance-This dance only works on a small group of people who can see the Whirling Blade; three people max. This Dance also works best on men; it rarely works on women. Basically, it takes advantage of the user's charisma (and allure) and has a 95%-20% chance to work (95% at best, 20% at worst) and cause those affected to fight with or for the Whirling Blade. If it fails, there's a 70-30 chance they can't attack the Whirling Blade, and there's a chance of them becoming smitten (99-5% for men, for women it depends on their orientation if you know what I mean....)
6. Vengeful Dance-This Dance is an automatic Critical (extra-powerful attack) if it lands. Magic multiplies the power of this attack by the amount of damage the Whirling Blade last received from the target.

So, my question is: **What different roles would a Whirling Blade have in society?**

For clarification: I know Whirling Blades likely will have a place on the battlefield, but I'm wondering what other roles they might have as well.

Consider:

1. 95% of Dancers are female, which might pose a problem for fielding them. As for the male 5%, that applies everything I put above for Bewitching Dance to women instead of men (reverses it's ratios).
2. They likely have potential as gladiators.
3. Since they are female, can fight, and can contribute to magical rituals with their Dances, witches will likely want Whirling Blade bodyguards. If that's a great idea and you feel like expanding on that, please do; otherwise explain why it's a terrible idea.
   spc
   **Why It's Important (If you've seen** [What Role Would Monks Have In a Fantasy Society?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/193176/what-role-would-monks-have-in-a-fantasy-society)**, feel free to ignore):** I'm trying to create the most detailed, realistic story possible here and that means understanding exactly how my Classes will fit into my fictional world. Yes, I'm applying logic to fiction. What good is a story that's complete nonsense?

Comment: I understand you have a lot of questions, but maybe some of the worldbuilding should be left to the creator..? What role do you want them to have? Cultural? Maybe a leftover from a religion? Maybe they are just self taught people? Maybe they are just like anyone. An average Joe that does this part time, or like a security guard?

Comment: DnD class system and realism are opposing forces, you wont be able to make them work together, no matter how hard you try. About role in society... Humans, in the real world... People are born with different genetic bonuses and disadvantages... Does this mean that every single tall person does the same exact job? Every single person with high coordination does the same thing? Every person with an incredible good hearing is a musician? If you want to be realistic, let them be whatever they want to be. World building should be about having fun, not playing god.

Comment: I know that in the litrpg community, classes rule, but I hate them and find their inclusion in fiction to be a very disturbing trend. I stopped gaming with any game that include classes in the seventies, and stop reading any series that even hints at classes.

Comment: Good grief, why do so many people hate Classes? People in Alendyias can be whoever they want to be, it's just that their Classes reveal where their true talents lie. In other words, they reflect who you _are_, your core self.

Comment: Trioxidane, Class-holders usually have their Classes from birth, and yes, I am looking for cultural roles. I am leaving most of the worldbuilding to myself, I'm just trying to cover how Classes would fit in as much detail as possible, and that involves asking people who know much more than I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Manufacturing, Hospitals and Protection**

**Manufacturing:** Factory owners hire dancers to buff their workers. The great thing about this is that the daily wage of a dancer is fixed, but their efficiency grows if the factory is larger.

Say a dancer costs 1 florin and they contribute a 20% buff. If your factory makes goods worth 10 florins per day then you now make 12 florins worth per day. Subtract the dancer's wage and you make a net profit of 1 florin, an increase of 10%. Now suppose the factory makes 100 florins per day. Then hiring a dancer earns 120, subtract the wage to get a 19% increase.

**Hospitals:** Presuming the dance cleans as well as closes the wounds it's a complete game changer for medecine in a medieval setting, where wound infection was a huge killer.

**Protection:** The dancer is a combatant with various utility abilities that make them a great bodyguard. The wound closing ability will let their master survive otherwise fatal blows. The hastening ability lets them run away faster. Bewitching will let you win the fight without killing the attackers. That way you can interrogate them afterwards.

Comment: Thank you Daron! This is genius; I thought Whirling Blades would be best suited for  the battlefield, but this gives them something to do off the battlefield! Plus, what makes them good for protection works for Hospitals and Manufacturing too....